# Set an AutomationProperties.AutomationId in code behind

Tags: wpf, code-behind

I have a WPF application that has a few legacy panels that were written mostly with code behind.  I need to set the AutomationProperties.AutomationId for the controls on the panel.  For example, this Checkbox

```
CheckBox myCheckbox = new CheckBox();
```

How can I set AutomationProperties.AutomationId?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
myCheckbox.SetValue(AutomationProperties.AutomationIdProperty, "checkBoxAutoID");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the Name property "myCheckbox" to the xaml checkbox definition to use the following LOC:

```
myCheckbox.SetValue(AutomationProperties.AutomationIdProperty, "checkBoxAutoID");
```

You can alternatively define in xaml:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="myCheckbox" 
... AutomationProperties.AutomationId="mycheckBoxAutoID" ...
</CheckBox >
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> AutomationProperties.SetAutomationId(myCheckbox, "YourDesiredname");

Ofcourse you need to include the namespace.

> using System.Windows.Automation;